# How to deal with returning a large List of items in Spring?

Tags: database, spring

This is just a theoretical question that I can't stop thinking about and I am actually wondering how would one solve it

I am currently working on some sort a forum website, and I have a Post entity which looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post")
public class Post extends Likable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column
    @Lob
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne
    private Account author;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Comment> comments;

    public Post(){}

    //getters and setters omitted
}
```

Now as you see, I have a field called comments, and when I load the post in my front end, I request the comments of the current post and then write them out in the post. And that works great.

But, this is for a post which contains like 20 comments. A array of 20 elements doesn't seem that bad. But what if the post contains like 2000 comments, or even more, like 20000 comments, how do you handle that? Also, is there a maximum size for List? Or a point where it's safe to say that you need to implement a different solution?

Again, this is just a theoretical question, and not something I will have to worry about right now since this is just a side project to learn Spring for me, but I am just wondering.

Comment: Typically, you paginate. Like when you search on Google: it displays one page of results at a time, not the 457524986 results at once.

Comment: @JBNizet How would you deal with this in the front end? If the user loads all the comments, you still have to store all of those 2000 comments somewhere

Comment: That's the whole point of pagination. The user does NOT load all the comments. It loads one page of comments at a time. Just like when you use google. You never display all the results at once. Only one page at a time. You've used google, right?

Comment: Have you ever used reddit? Try loading in all comments in a thread, and you will see that it loads all the comments, and it doesn't redirect you to a new page each time you want to load other comments

Comment: No, I've never used reddit. But anyway, reddit wouldn't be a good example to explain pagination then. I didn't take that as an example. I took Google. If you want to avoid loading 20000 comments in memory, you typically do it using pagination, like google does it (not reddit, google). That said, I just went to reddit, and they use pagination too. Load a page with many comments, go to the end of the page, and you'll see a link like "400 more replies".

Comment: Yes, and when you click on that link, it doesn't take you to a new page like Google does, it loads the 400 replies on the same page, under the already loaded comments... Yes, they might use pagination, but not in the same way as Google. They still have to store ALL of the comments somewhere, IF the user chooses to load all of them

Comment: But your question is about Spring. Spring is on the server, not in the browser. So assuming reddit is implemented with Spring, Spring would never have to load 20000 comments at once in memory. It only loads one slice of comments at a time and sends that slice to the browser. The browser is then free to do whatever it wants: add them all to the page or store them in local storage, and only load in memory the ones that are currently dsplayed in the browser viewport for example.

Comment: Okay fair enough, and it's totally acceptable to store 20000 comments in a single Array in JS and load all of them in React?

Comment: In an array, maybe. In the DOM, probably not. But as I said in my previous comment, you can use pagination there too, by only adding to the DOM (or even in memory) the ones that are currently displayed in the viewport. That's called "virtual scrolling". See https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview for an example and explanation (not using react, but you could do the same with react)

Comment: Hmh okay, interesting, thanks